# Need help regex optional whitespace before negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am currently building a regex to find all passwords in files. The current regex is :

```
(?:pass)(?:word)?(?:[\ ]{0,1})(?:[:=;,]{1})(?:[\ ]{0,1})(?!function)(.[^\s]*)
```

The problem is I don't want lines containing "function" after the optional whitespace.

```
password = potato123! found, is ok
$dbpass=train123; = found, is ok
pass:function($pass); = not found, is ok
$dbpassword= function('dontfindme'); = found, should not be found
```

See it in action:
https://regex101.com/r/zT1kI3/35

Thank you!

Guillaume

Comment: Is this a PCRE pattern (as indicated by the use of regex101)? The issue is the backtracking into `(?:[\ ]{0,1})` once the lookahead fails.

Comment: Not sure what is a PCRE pattern but I plan to use it using PowerGrep software. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to move the look for the optional whitespace to be part of the check for `function`:

```
(?:pass)(?:word)?(?:[\ ]{0,1})(?:[:=;,]{1})(?![\ ]{0,1}function)(.[^\s]*)
```

[Updated regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zT1kI3/37)

Comment: Thank you ! it works like a charm but can you please explain why the other lines are still working with a whitespace if it is part of the negative look ahead ?

Comment: Because the space in those instances isn't followed by `function`.  Note that this solution won't find any passwords that happen to be `function` either.

Comment: Mitigated it by filtering for "function(" instead. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Does this regex match to your other samples?

```
(?:pass|password)\s*[:=;,]\s*(?!\s{0,}function)(\S*)
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/PXWw6j/1